# при выполнении скрипта ошибка 429 Too Many Requests. За сутки отправлено меньше 20 запросов. В чем может быть проблема?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Сам скрипт (до сегодняшнего дня работал):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <title>Маршрут доставки. Дистанция </title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px }
      #map { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"  type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://yandex.st/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var MyMap, route;

    ymaps.ready(init);

    function init(){  
        myMap = new ymaps.Map ("map", {
            center: [53.98, 47.78],
            zoom: 10,
            controls: ['default']
        });
        myMap.behaviors.enable('scrollZoom');
        myMap.behaviors.disable('dblClickZoom');
        ymaps.route(
                    ['Ульяновск, Уютная 8', 'Самарская область,  г. Суходол, ул. Школьная, д. 1'],
                    {mapStateAutoApply: true}).then(function (router) {
            route && myMap.geoObjects.remove(route);
            route = router;    
           myMap.geoObjects.add(route);
            var points = route.getPaths();
            dlMar = route.getLength()/1000; 
            document.title = ['Дистанция: '+ dlMar.toFixed(2)];     
            var way = [];
            var dlPath = [];
            lastPoint = points.getLength() - 1;
    for (var j=0; j<1; j++) {
       way[j] = points.get(j);
       dlPath[j] = way[j].getLength()/1000;
        document.title = [document.title + ' часть '+j+'='+dlPath[j].toFixed(2)];}
                            for (var i=0; i < 1; i++) { 
                            try{
    points.get(i).set("iconContent",i);
                            }
                            catch(e){
                            }}
        }, function (error) {
            alert("Возникла ошибка: " + error.message);
        });
         }
   </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map" style="width:1024px;height:600px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Можно ссылку на страницу с проблемой? Вот тут работает: http://jsfiddle.net/aspmvLrn/

Comment: Через  jsfiddle.net тоже проверял - работает, все в порядке. Для теста сохраняю в файл html и открываю в google chrome, там уже не работает

Comment: Вопросы про лимиты и условия использования сервиса лучше задавать техподдержке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

API нужно использовать с ключом, как описано [в документации](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/dg/concepts/load-docpage/?from=SO), когда вы делаете запросы без ключа вас нельзя идентифицировать как отдельный сервис со своим лимитом и это может быть причиной "превышения" лимита.

Comment: Да, все именно так, как Вы сказали. С ключом все заработало. Спасибо!